# Is it possible to take a stored procedure name as input parameter in another stored procedure and execute it?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have a set of stored procedures with the same interface and one of these stored procedures will be passed to a runner stored procedure as an input parameter. How can I execute this stored procedure within the runner proc.

I tried this by using dynamic SQL. The code snippet I wrote for this:

```
v_proc_query := ':1(:2, :3)';
execute immediate v_proc_query using p_proc_name, p_param1, p_param2;
```

But the above statement give  error: `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`
I'm using Oracle 12c.

What is the right approach to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = par_deptno;
  9    dbms_output.put_line('count = ' || l_cnt);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test_2 (par_proc_name in varchar2, par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    l_str := 'begin ' ||
  6                dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_proc_name) ||
  7                  '(' || par_deptno || ');' ||
  8             'end;';
  9    execute immediate l_str;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test_2('p_test', 10);
count = 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This actually works. But the actual set of proc has one SYS_REFCUSROR as out parameter. I declared an SYS_REFCURSOR variable in the runner proc and tried to pass it, but this gives an error.